# How to Open base64 String to Pdf in flutter web

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-test

In flutter web application,I upload pdf file to base64 in flrebase database.How to open base64 string to pdf in flutter web.
for upload file I use below code

```
 html.InputElement uploadInput = html.FileUploadInputElement();
uploadInput.multiple = true;
uploadInput.draggable = true;
uploadInput.click();

uploadInput.onChange.listen((e) {
  final files = uploadInput.files;
  final file = files[0];
  final reader = new html.FileReader();

  reader.onLoadEnd.listen((e) {
    _handleResult(reader.result);
  });
  reader.readAsDataUrl(file);
```

In handle result method

```
  void _handleResult(Object result) {
setState(() {
  Uint8List  _bytesData = Base64Decoder().convert(result.toString().split(",").last);
  List<int> _selectedFile = _bytesData;
  print("_handleResult==>${_bytesData.toString()}");
  var base64Str = base64.encode(_bytesData);
    });
```

so How I display **base64Str** string to  pdf in flutter web